# Unable to re-enable bluetooth after turning it off in gnome-control-center

Tags: ubuntu, gnome, bluetooth

I've had some issues with Bluetooth for a few months now and when I finally got around to troubleshooting it I got stuck:

The Problem: When I turn off Bluetooth in the gnome-control-center, the UI gets unresponsive and the only way to re-enable it I found is rebooting.

What I've tried:

- connect devices through blueman: got the error "Connection Failed: Resource not Ready"
- typing `systemctl restart bluetooth`. Still not able to connect to devices through gnome-control-center or blueman
- following [a comment from Github](https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman/issues/538#issuecomment-613548788) I tried

```
bluetoothctl
power on
discoverable on
pairable on
scan on
```

All the commands seemed to work flawlessly except the `scan on` which threw "org.bluez.Error.NotReady", but when running bluetoothctl show, I get:

```
    Name: pop-os
    Alias: pop-os
    Class: 0x00000000
    Powered: no
    Discoverable: yes
    DiscoverableTimeout: 0x00000000
    Pairable: yes
    UUID: Message Notification Se.. (00001133-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: OBEX Object Push          (00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Message Access Server     (00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: IrMC Sync                 (00001104-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Vendor specific           (00005005-0000-1000-8000-0002ee000001)
    UUID: Headset AG                (00001112-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Phonebook Access Server   (0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: OBEX File Transfer        (00001106-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d0538
    Discovering: no
    Roles: central
    Roles: peripheral
```

I am not sure why I have "powered: no" above.
I guess that means `bluetoothctl power on` did not work after all, even though I got "Changing power on succeeded" back?

Any hints on what I should try next would be very appreciated.

OS: Pop-OS (Ubuntu 21.04) with [regolith](https://regolith-linux.org/) on top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a fix here https://askubuntu.com/a/1167726/1197984:
Running the following in the shell solved my issue:

```
sudo rmmod btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

(Sorry seems like I don't have enough reputation yet to accept my own answer?)

Comment: You have to wait 48 hours before you can accept it.